# Facing an error in program of image capturing and processing using opencv(cv2) and python

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

In the following program, it captures and processes image runtime. But I am facing a lot problems in the code. The first problem is, when camera is initialized for the  first time and if it is unable to detect red colour in captured frame then it gives following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mukund/Desktop/Checknewcod/attempone.py", line 23, in <module>
    M=cv2.moments(best_cnt)
NameError: name 'best_cnt' is not defined
```

Sometimes it gives following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mukund/Desktop/New logic/GridTestcal1.py", line 287, in <module>
    fun2()
  File "/home/mukund/Desktop/New logic/GridTestcal1.py", line 230, in fun2
    M=cv2.moments(best_cnt)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'best_cnt' referenced before assignment
```

The code is as follows.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
num = 0
while True:           
    flag, img2 = capture.read()
    flag=capture.set(3,640)
    flag=capture.set(4,480)
    cv2.imwrite('pic'+str(num)+'.jpg', img2)
    img1=cv2.imread('pic'+str(num)+'.jpg')
    img=cv2.blur(img1,(3,3))
    ORANGE_MIN=np.array([170,160,60],np.uint8)
    ORANGE_MAX=np.array([180,255,255],np.uint8)
    hsv_img=cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    frame_thresh=cv2.inRange(hsv_img,ORANGE_MIN,ORANGE_MAX)
    contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(frame_thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    x_area=0
    for cnt in contours:
        area=cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area>x_area:
        x_area=area
        best_cnt=cnt     
    M=cv2.moments(best_cnt)
    cx,cy=int(M['m10']/M['m00']),int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
    cv2.circle(frame_thresh,(cx,cy),5,255,-1)
    cv2.imwrite('pic1'+str(num)+'.jpg',frame_thresh)
    print cx,cy
    if num == 30:
        capture.release()
        break         
    num += 1
```

Is there any efficient way to implement above code such as using video processing?

Comment: btw, indentation error after `if area>x_area:`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error, you should check that the number of returned contours is > 0.
In some cases no coutours are detected so best_cnt is not set so the error is telling you that you are referencing it before defining that variable.

```
for cnt in contours:
    area=cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area>x_area:  # I believe your code is indented wrongly here
        x_area=area
        best_cnt=cnt

if len(cnt) > 0:  # In some cases no coutours are detected so best_cnt is not set.   
    M=cv2.moments(best_cnt)
    cx,cy=int(M['m10']/M['m00']),int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
    cv2.circle(frame_thresh,(cx,cy),5,255,-1)
    cv2.imwrite('pic1'+str(num)+'.jpg',frame_thresh)
    print cx,cy

if num == 30:
    capture.release()
    break         
num += 1
```

The bulk of the processing time for your code, I believe, should be in reading and writing the image. If you are getting the frames from a video camera, then things might be slightly better, especially if its frame rate is high. If you can choose to write the frames every say `k` images then it might help avoid dropping frames.
Also, it would help if you can narrow down the region of interest (ROI) and only perform the image processing algorithms such as cvtColor, inRange, and findContours on it.

Some minor tweaks would be to move the declaration of `ORANGE_MIN/MAX` outside of the while loop.

Comment: I tried things that u told but it was giving same error so I used flag and error is resolved. Thanks.